# Modifying state from inside .onAppear causes error 'Modifying state during view update, this will cause undefined behavior'

Tags: swift, swiftui

**When testing on a real device**, I get the `Modifying state during view update, this will cause undefined behavior` issue for the code below. Tested on an iPhone 11. On the simulator, the issue doesn't arise and the code works as expected.

From [what I can gather](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-fix-modifying-state-during-view-update-this-will-cause-undefined-behavior), modifying state **from inside .onAppear** is fine.

What's going on here? Why am I getting this error?

```
struct Clouds: View {
    @State private var cloudOffset: CGFloat = 0.0
    @State private var cloudOffset2: CGFloat = 0.0

    @EnvironmentObject var mainData: MainData
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geo in
            if mainData.animateClouds {
                Image("cloudsBlurry")
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFit()
                    .offset(x: self.cloudOffset, y: 0.0)
                    .onAppear {
                        let baseAnimation = Animation.linear(duration: 30)
                        let repeated = baseAnimation.repeatForever(autoreverses: true)

                        withAnimation(repeated) {
                            self.cloudOffset += geo.size.width * 0.50 //Error here
                        }
                    }
                Image("cloudsBlurry3")
                    .resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                    .frame(height: geo.size.height * 2)
                    .offset(x: self.cloudOffset2, y: 0.0)
                    .onAppear {
                        let baseAnimation = Animation.linear(duration: 30)
                        let repeated = baseAnimation.repeatForever(autoreverses: true)
                        
                        self.cloudOffset2 = -geo.size.width //Error here
                        
                        withAnimation(repeated) {
                            self.cloudOffset2 += geo.size.width * 0.50 //Error here
                        }
                    }
            } else {
                Image("cloudsBlurry")
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFit()
                    .offset(x: 0.0, y: 0.0)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have cycle, because `offset(x: self.cloudOffset` dependency and `self.cloudOffset += geo` force refresh due to above dependency.

Try to make update with a bit delay, to give current refresh to finish with current offset value:

```
withAnimation(repeated) {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
       self.cloudOffset += geo.size.width * 0.50
    }
}
```